# Is there a workaround for this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, complex

The command

```
Integrate[Exp[a*Exp[I*x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

produces

> ConditionalExpression[0, a == 0]

which is not correct in view of

```
Integrate[1, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

> 2 π

The result should be equal to  $2\pi$ for each complex number $a$. The question arises: is there a workaround for this integral?

Comment: Can we consider this a bug?

Comment: `Integrate[Exp[a*Exp[I*x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Assumptions -> a == 0]` ?

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: Thank you. Unfortunately, this works only for $a=0$. Tha command Integrate[Exp[a*Exp[I*x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Assumptions -> Re[a] != 0] outputs  $0$.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk:: The parameter $a$ is assumed to be complex, so $a \neq 0 $ is not equivaltnt to $ a>0 \vee a < 0$.

Comment: [Rubi](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) returns zero as well.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ  Yes, it certainly looks like a bug and should be reported.

Comment: This seems like a very old bug. Could you please report it to tech support?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh I will think of your suggestion. BTW, I submitted more than a hundred MMA bugs and was awarded by a nice cup from Wolfram. This cup recalls me the WIC generosity again and again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One workaround is to shift the main computation from integration to summation. Start from Taylor series for `a` and get a general `SeriesCoefficient`, which is much simpler and integrates nicely:

```
Integrate[SeriesCoefficient[Exp[a Exp[I x]], {a, 0, n}], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

> [image]

We switched the order of summation and integration. Now what is left is to sum back:

```
Sum[(2 Sin[n π])/(n n!) a^n,{n,0,∞}]
```

> ```
> Out[]= 2 π
> ```

This is also quite clear from the fact that for all `n>=0` all terms are zero. And the only contributing `n=0` term is equal to:

```
Limit[(2 Sin[n π])/(n n!) a^n,n->0]
```

> Out[]= 2 π

Comment: Please notice that your sum has only one contribution, the term corresponding to `n=0`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks yep, I added it for clarity. I think OP wants Mathematica to figure it out automatically in the least number of steps :-)

Comment: The only place I dislike is Limit[(2 Sin[n π])/(n n!) a^n,n->0] =2*Pi.

Comment: I find SeriesCoefficient[Exp[a Exp[I x]], {a, 0, 0}] to be a better way.

Comment: It should be noticed that the workaround suggested by you does not fix the bug.

Answer (score 6):

One can use the fact that:

```
D[Exp[a Exp[I x]], x ] === I a D[Exp[a Exp[I x]], a ]
(* True *)
```

to integrate by parts and get zero:
    $$int(a) \equiv \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx\ e^{a\ e^{i\ x}}$$
    \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{d a} int(a) & = & \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx\ e^{i\ x}\ e^{a\ e^{i\ x}} \\
 & = & \frac{1}{i a} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx\ \frac{d}{dx} e^{a\ e^{i\ x}} \\
 & = & \frac{1}{i a}\ \left[e^{a\ e^{i\ x}} \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} \\
 & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore, at least to first order in `a`, the integral is independent of `a` and equal to the value at `a=0`, i.e. `2 Pi`.

Comment: Can you elaborate " the integral is independent of a" in details?

Comment: @user64494 The precedure above proves that the first derivative of the integral with respect to `a` vanishes. I think it could be proven along the same lines that also higher order derivatives vanish, therefore the integral is a constant function (as you expected).

Comment: @b.gatessucks : Integration by parts gives `\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Pi]\), \(\[Pi]\)]\(Exp[
    a\ Exp[I\ x]] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) = \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Pi]\), \(\[Pi]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(I\ a\)] \((Exp[
       a\ Exp[I\ x]])\)' \[DifferentialD]x\)\) = 
  1/(I a) (Exp[a Exp[I \[Pi]]] - Exp[a Exp[-I \[Pi]]]) 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(=\), \(?\)]\) 0` seems to confirm  the MMA result? Where is my mistake?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please see edit. I think that the integral equals `2 \Pi` and that _Mathematica_ has a bug.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thanks for the edit, very tricky, now I got it! But still I cannot find the error in the conclusion of my comment (sorry, I don't know how to bring it in a nicer shape).

Comment: @UlrichNeumann What's zero is the derivative on the integral with respect to `a`, not the integral itself.

Comment: @b.gatessucks That's it, thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. A nice workaround!

Answer (score 6):

The issue here can be identified by evaluating the indefinite integral,

```
s = Integrate[Exp[a*Exp[I*x]], x]
(* -I ExpIntegralEi[a E^(I x)] *)
```

Now,

```
(s /. x -> Pi) - (s /. x -> -Pi)
(* 0 *)
```

The catch is that ExpIntegralEi[z] has a branch cut, extending along the negative real axis from zero to negative infinity.  So, the correct way to apply the limits, at least for `a > 0`, is

```
Limit[s, x -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow", Assumptions -> a > 0] - 
    Limit[s, x -> -Pi, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> a > 0]
(* 2 π *)
```

as desired.  I presume, but have not tried to prove, that employing the proper `Limit` options will yield the desired result for all `a`.  Certainly,

```
Integrate[Exp[(-141/10 + 397/100 I) Exp[I*x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

and every other specific value of `a` I have tried yields `2 π`.

Answer (score 2):

Strange behavior.

```
$Assumptions = a \[Element] Reals

Integrate[Exp[a*Exp[I*x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
(*ConditionalExpression[0, a >= 0]*)

Integrate[Exp[a*Exp[I*x]] // ExpToTrig, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
ConditionalExpression[2*Pi, a >= 0]
```

I would think both should be the same, but no.  Also

```
$Assumptions = a > 0

Integrate[Exp[a*Exp[I*x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
(*2*Pi*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Making the change `z==Exp[I*x]` in 14.0 on Windows 10, one obtains

```
Integrate[Exp[a*Exp[I*x]]*I*Exp[I*x]/(I*Exp[I*x]),{x,-Pi,Pi}]==
ContourIntegrate[Exp[a*z]/z/I, z \[Element] Disk[]]
```

> `2*Pi`

Unfortunately,

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][Exp[a*Exp[I*x]],{x, -Pi, Pi}],
z, z == Exp[I*x]];Activate[IntegrateChangeVariables[
Inactive[Integrate][E^(a E^(I x)), {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], z, 
z == E^(I x)], Unevaluated[Integrate]]
```

produces `IntegrateChangeVariables[ConditionalExpression[0, a == 0], z,  z == E^(I x)]`.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be the numerical evaluation

```
int[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[a*Exp[I*x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
{int[0], int[1], int[I]} // Chop
{6.28319, 6.28319, 6.28319}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, a symbolic result is requiered.